# How can we access component const variable in Jest, enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

```
const PassengerTable = () => {
  const inFlight = window.location.pathname.includes("in-flight");
}
```

How we can access const inflight in test case, so that i change its value true or false, based on that i will complete my branches.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://circleci.com/blog/continuously-testing-react-applications-with-jest-and-enzyme/) hope you will get your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution, We can do this using global window object

global.window = { location: { pathname: "/check-in" } };